# How to embed a database into my vuejs app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, vue.js

I know this is a "generic" question, but please read it before judging:

I try to create a vuejs fullstack application that i can build and run with a single command. I use the vue-cli to create and build a project. Included is express and node (works fine). But I cannot figure out how to add database functionality to it. I thought mongodb and mongoose would fit, until I learned that I need a separate mongodb server running instead of getting it embedded within my build.

Is this even possible? I mean, android apps ship with SQLite that every app can use. Where do I need to research to get this job done? Google tells me to use mongoose, but it is not embedded as it seems.

Comment: Vuejs is a front-end framework, you don't usually embed databases in there. And there's plenty of embedded databases, the most popular being SQLite, the ExpressJS website even has a simple example how to use it: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html#sqlite

Comment: @UnholySheep If I can ship this with my app, I will definitely have a look at it! Thank you very much! EDIT: It looks like this is only an "in memory" database with no persistence layer?

Comment: SQLite can be used either purely in-memory or with persistence (in the form of database-files). You can read more about it on their [official site](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) and there's also some small explanations in e.g.: [the sqlite3 docs](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#new-sqlite3databasefilename-mode-callback)

Comment: @UnholySheep If you turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it. It really helped, especially that link with the doc. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested, as an answer:

Databases are usually part of the back-end (in this case nodejs). There's plenty of choices for embedable databases, the most popular one is [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html).
It can be used either purely "in memory" or with persistence in the form of "database files". More information how to use it in node can be found in the [`node-sqlite3` documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#new-sqlite3databasefilename-mode-callback)